# How do I create a UIImage from a CGImage in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, core-foundation, cgimage

I'm trying to create a `UIImage` from the `ALAssetsGroup#posterImage` method. In Objective-C, I could simply call `[UIImage imageWithCGImage:group.posterImage]` but in Swift, `UIImage(CGImage: group.posterImage)` gives me a compiler error:

```
Could not find an overload for 'init' that accepts the supplied arguments
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The real problem here is the "could not find an overload" message is not very informative. I suggest you file an enhancement request about that. Swift could do a lot better with its error messages.

Comment: @Fattie Check the date: this question was about the original version of Swift, not the current version. And there was no crash - it was a compiler error.

Answer (score 32):

If you look at the docs in Xcode6 you will see that `posterImage()` returns a `Unmanaged<CGImage>!` (in Swift, in ObjC it returns a `CGImageRef`). After some investigation from the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/buildingcocoaapps/WorkingWithCocoaDataTypes.html) I found this:

> When you receive an unmanaged object from an unannotated API, you
>   should immediately convert it to a memory managed object before you
>   work with it.

So your solution would be:

```
UIImage(CGImage: group.posterImage().takeUnretainedValue())
```

Comment: That doesn't help, but the error message I got from that code did: "no method for `() -> Unmanaged<CGImage>!`". So `posterImage` is a `func` rather than a property. Adding parens after posterImage did the trick.

Answer (score 13):

##### Update for 2023 syntax:

```
someImage = UIImage(cgImage: someCGImage)
```

A typical example is taking the image from a CALayer:

```
someImage = UIImage(cgImage: donorLayer.contents as! CGImage)
```

---

Are you sure group.posterImage is not an optional?

have you tried

```
var img = UIImage(CGImage: group.posterImage!) // 2010s syntax
```

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. The above code gives the same compiler error.

Comment: This is the normal approach and works perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example that should work for you with Xcode 8.3:

```
    let frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), size: CGSize(width: 1920, height: 1080))
    let cgImage = CIContext().createCGImage(CIImage(color: .black()), from: frame)!
    let uiImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use init with CGIImage:

```
UIImage.init(CGImage: group.posterImage, scale: self.scale, orientation: .UpMirrored)
```

Comment: if i have to increase the scale of the image how would be that possible ?

Comment: just set the scale you want with a CGFloat value